# libtorch 1000 warnings on MSVC++

Tags: c++, libtorch

I downloaded libtorch from https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

The file that I downloaded was: libtorch-win-shared-with-deps-2.0.1+cpu.zip

I have successfully added in the include and lib folders for libtorch, and everything compiles and links ok (using Microsoft CL), with one exception: there are like 1000 warnings generated by the compiler. Not errors, but warnings. Is this normal?

Thanks for your time and expertise.

Comment: It's a multi-kLOC C++ library with dozens of dependencies. Yes, it's normal.